# Static methods - calling a function

Tags: php

```
echo System\Core\Request::factory()->execute();
```

factory() is called first, constructor is next, and execute() is the last here. It of course works as expected.

Request class contains a couple of NON-STATIC attributes. I set all of them in the factory method. Like this:

```
public static function factory()
{
   if(! Request::$initial)
   {
      $request = Request::$initial = Request::$current = new Request();
      $request->foo = 'bar';
   }
   else
   {
      Request::$current = $request = new Request();
      $request->foo = 'aaa';
   }
   return Request::$current;
}
```

Constructor comes next:

```
public function __construct()
{
   echo $this->foo; // displays empty string
   echo Request::$current->foo; // trying to get property of non-object
}
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

The constructor is called before you have set `foo` because you set it in the factory after instantiating the request.

```
public static function factory()
{
   if(! Request::$initial)
   {
      // constructor is called as part of this line
      $request = Request::$initial = Request::$current = new Request();

      // foo is set AFTER the constructor is called
      $request->foo = 'bar';
   }
   else
   {
      // constructor is called as part of this line
      Request::$current = $request = new Request();

      // foo is set AFTER the constructor is called
      $request->foo = 'aaa';
   }
   return Request::$current;
}
```